# Is there a way to capture console controls (keyboard/mouse/remote) in OSX so they can be replicated on another machine?

Tags: macos, synchronization, remote-desktop, vnc, keyboard-hook

I need to mirror GUI console activity happening on one Macbook so that it is duplicated on a second identical Macbook.

The idea is to control an application that will run on two Macbooks simultaneously.  The application is sort of a presentation with two variations in content, but identical controls.  Think of it as two versions of PowerPoint presentation with some slides that are different.

I'm thinking that it may be possible to capture the keypresses and mouse events on one Mac, then use RFB protocol to send these across the network to the other Mac.  I'm looking at [rfbproxy](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/rfbproxy/) and [rfbplaymacro](http://cyberelk.net/tim/rfbplaymacro/), but these are somewhat inelegant hacks, and any solution built on these will also be a bit of a hack.  And of course, I'd prefer to avoid a solution that requires me to compile and perhaps debug software that hasn't been touched in half a decade.  :-)

I could conceivably use [Cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) or [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) (from MacPorts) to initiate console events on the "slave" Mac.  But then I don't know what I'd use to capture the events on the "master".  Or would an xdotool-based solution require that both Macs be slaves, and then use some other device as a master?

Input devices could be a presentation mouse, an Apple remote, or in a pinch, the keyboard of on of the Macbooks or even a third device.

Can you suggest tools?  Or is there another strategy I haven't thought of?

Comment: Maybe the Synergy project can help you? (http://synergy-foss.org/)

Comment: Close, but I need to duplicate console activity, not just move focus to another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to synchronise systems like this that are NOT Macs a few years ago using rfbproxy and rfbplaymacro which you already know about.  The systems were both X terminals running at the same resolution.  We still had problems because of different font size settings putting application controls in different places, but the basic VNCiness of the solution seemed to work just fine.

That said, if you want to write a stand-alone application to send stuff using osascript or cliclick or xdotool, and you have a wii, you might get some joy from [DarwiinRemote](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwiin-remote/).

Comment: Clever idea.  I'll investigate.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/ .  Check the "Supported hardware" link, and select "Bluetooth" since you can't use Infrared on Macbook Airs.  It'll also let you use your iPhone or iPod Touch as a remote.  I have no way of knowing whether it'll work inside your application, but if it's browser-based, it should be fine as it supports Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

If the computers are in the same room, a single Apple Remote can control both Macs as long as the remote is not paired to either one. I'm assuming you need a solution that will work over any arbitrary distance, though.

Have you considered AppleScript? It's pretty good at sending keystrokes to ssh-accessible Macs. The receiving application doesn't even need to be aware of AppleScript (i.e. scriptable). You'll just have to be sure GUI scripting is enabled on the targets by checking the **Enable access for assistive devices** option in the Universal Access system prefs panel.

Here's an example of a shell command that will send a keystroke to the frontmost app via applescript:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"a\""
```

If you set up key-based ssh auth between the master and slaves you can simply tack ssh onto the front of this command:

```
ssh slave osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"a\""
```

For elegance, you could wrap any number of desired keystrokes into a menu-based bash script and run it from a third computer.

Comment: Alas, a single Apple remote won't work because at least one of the computers is a Macbook Air, which doesn't appear to have an IR input.  Also, SENDING the commands (via cliclick or xdotool or tell (thank you for that)) isn't much of a problem, but if I go that route I don't know how to capture.  Though as you indicate, a third computer with a custom control tool might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Kindof convoluted, but you could use [clusterSSH for OSX](http://code.google.com/p/csshx/) to start shell sessions from a third machines master window, and then send commands to the two slaves. This could be paired with a screen control utility similar to the ones you list above, another of which is [pymaCursor](https://github.com/pudquick/pymaCursor).

If everything could instead be recorded in advance, you could try good ol' applescript/automator recording, or a newer project like sikuli - http://sikuli.org/

Comment: It's sounding like the only solutions involve a control system on a third machine.  pymaCursor is another good thing to have in one's arsenal, thanks for that.